# Problem with Entity Data Model in Dynamic Data Web Site

Tags: .net, asp.net, dynamic-data

I'm trying to set up a dynamic data entities web site, exactly following the [MS walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488469.aspx), but I can't register my model.  My web site is called 'DynExtensions', and the model gets generated in the namespace 'DynExtensions.App_Code', but this namespace is not visible in the rest of the project, i.e. I get a compile error if I add a 'using' with that namespace.  What is the walkthrough doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MS walkthrough (which I have since added a link to) says to add a **Dynamic Data Entities Web *Site*** project, but my templates only allow a **Dynamic Data Entities Web *Application*** project.  Since there were no other options, I overlooked this critical difference.  I over came that particular obstacle by simply adding the model to the root of the application, not the out of place 'App_Code' folder.  From then I took only minutes to have the poc site working.  It looks very promising.

*Aside: I wish they would stick to the web site model introduced as a development for ASP.NET 2.0, or publicly revert to the web application model, and not sneak it in wherever they can.*

Answer (score 0):

Do you have several projects in your solution? If so, are you missing a project reference.

Also you would get the same error if the project containing the model did not build.

Could also be caused by a missing public statement, but not probable in your case.